# css-grid rendering differently in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, css-grid

Heads up - I'm new here, and new to some of the css-grid stuff. Bear with me if this isn't a peak Stack Overflow question.

I'm implementing the Slick jquery slider/carousel plugin into the website. However, I need the carousel slides to (a) all be the exact same height, and (b) be the same height as the slide with the tallest content. I'm getting two different responses on Firefox and Chrome when I try to modify the css to allow for this

I have copied the plugin's css straight into the css of the files I'm working with (so it becomes just part of the native css) so I have better control over it.

I've modified this new pasted css slightly from the original script `slick.css` file, but only by modifying one the `display: none;` to `display: grid;` on the `.slick-list` selector. This deals with the issue on Firefox, but not on Chrome.

All code that I am using is located here. I have added one line of code `background-color: red;` to the `.slick-list` selector to illustrate the space that SHOULD be taken up by slides that are shorter than the tallest slide: https://codepen.io/kyleshepherddev/pen/eqMOxm

I'm not sure what I'm expecting - the css I'm using may not be the right way to fix the problem. We have a client who used this plugin on their site, and I'm mucking around trying to figure out exactly how to fix it. The content of the slider shifts a bit from slide to slide, so the goal is to make ALL slides the SAME HEIGHT as the slide with the most content in it.

Works like a charm in Firefox; doesn't work at all in Chrome.

Comment: Please post all code necessary to reproduce the problem in the question itself.

Comment: Should I have pasted all the code that was already in the codepen I linked to? (I'm new around here, so this is a serious question.)

Comment: If codepen one day ceases to exist, your demo dies and your question here becomes useless. Yes, it's always important to include your code in the question itself to ensure the long-term viability of the post. (That said, codepen and jsfiddle demos are good additions to the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Simple update these two classes:

`.slick-list` to `display: flex` instead of `display: grid`

`.slick-track` to `display: flex` instead of `display: block`

Comment: That worked. Is there a specification reason why `grid` wasn't working cross-browser? I couldn't find any reason why `grid` wouldn't work just the same on Chrome in my research.

Comment: I'm not sure in this particular case sorry. I would really appreciate if you could click on accept my answer above though if it works?

Comment: I did. Message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."